# Using AI to identify similar browsing pattern

Tags: gdpr

I understand that storing any hash or IP that can identify "user uniquely" is against GDPR. I am planning to use user browsing patterns to see if a similar or the same user had previously visited the website. (Scroll pattern/click frequency and so on.) There will not be any hardware related information saved or any cookie saved on the client side, just the pages visited and "way" a user navigated the website.
Is such a method GDPR compliant?

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that storing any hash or IP that can identify "user uniquely" is against GDPR.

That is not correct. However any data which is identifiably associated with a an individual human, including any data which could be used to identify that human, is generally "Personal data", and may not be processed (which includes storing it) without a lawful basis, if the GDPR applies. Any of the [six lawful bases](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-6-gdpr/) allowed by the GDPR may be used, including consent, and the legitimate interest of the data controller.

The GDPR does not generally specify that particular technological solutions are permitted or forbidden. If this usage pattern could reasonably be used to identify a particular person, or to single out a person from among a group of people, it is probably personal data, and a lawful basis would be required. Otherwise, not.

As for whether such a person is "identifiable" if use of this technique permits the Data Controller to identify two visits at separate times as having been made by the same person, when the later visit is still in progress or is recent, the IP for that visit will still be available, and thus could be associated with the first visit as well. And even if that is not done, such a technique could permit building a profile of such a person, including the actions taken on different visits. I think that would be enough to make this "personal data".

Comment: Thank you very much , but it is impossible to uniquely tell if it is the same person , it will only be in probability of say 90% that it might be same user. It will never be possible to uniquely identify with full certainty that it is the same user. Will GDPR still apply ?

Comment: Yes, of course. It’s still personally identifying information, even if it isn’t foolproof.

Comment: A 90% assurance might well be enough to "single out" a person from among a group, or limit the possibilities to a small group out of a large one. That might be enough for the information to be considered personal data, and the GDPR rules to apply. But Legitimate interest might well be a valid lawful basis.

Comment: @avila You're looking at it incorrectly. The issue isn't whether data X can be shown to be related to the same person as data Y. The issue is whether the *actual person* can be identified from data X or Y.  E.g. if you were storing the user's email address then the person may be identifiable from that. If you are storing the fact that a user moved the mouse in a certain way, then so long as you can't identify the person from that mouse movement data (or from the mouse data combined with some other data) then the GDPR does not apply to it.

Comment: @JBentley The GDPR applies to the personal data of unknown and practically unknowable persons; if it is personal data the GDPR applies even if the actual individual cannot be identified. In any event, those mouse movements are likely to be as unique as a signature and, when combined with other data (even data the OP doesn’t have), could identify an individual.

Comment: @DaleM *"if it is personal data the GDPR applies even if the actual individual cannot be identified"* - can you explain what you mean here? Per Article 4(1), if no individual is identifiable then *by definition* it is not personal data in the first place (*"‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person"*). On the second point, it's hard to imagine any data you could combine with some mouse moments to be able to identify a person (unless they happen to have recorded those same mouse movements somewhere).

Comment: @JBentley the OP is indicating that the activities on the page are sufficient for him to link the same user across time. That makes them an identifiable individual- it doesn’t matter that you can’t put a name to the face as it were.